# Create user without email

Tags: guest-user, experience-cloud

I have an external system integrated with Salesforce. I import contacts from that external system and create the users in salesforce. Not all of the contacts have an email address.

**My Requirement:**

I need to create community users from those contacts without emails.

**What I think to solve the problem:**

1. Use a random unique email address while creating a user from contact.
2. Each user without email will request a password by clicking a forgot password link in a custom lightning component as a guest user.
3. To verify the guest user we are planning to add some questions to be answered in a custom lightning component.
   Upon verifying the answers, we will send the password reset link to their mobile via SMS. We can use 3rd party services like Twilio to send this password reset link.
4. The user then can input their username, password and thus create a valid credential to log in to the community.

My solution solely depends on few answers

```
a. Can guest users read and write to some selective fields on the User/Contact object?
b. Can guest users call API from salesforce? We need to call Twilio API to send the OTP/pass reset link
c. Can guest user call resetPassword(userId, sendUserEmail) method?
```

For point [b], we can create a public API, I guess and for point [c], we can wrap `resetPassword()` in another public API. But I am not sure about point [a], I see that I can edit the read, write permission in the contact object of Guest User Profiles but not in the user object.

Or can you suggest any other solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "create community users ... without emails"? Do you mean, don't send a "welcome" email? Or do you mean don't set the User record's Email field? Why are you not using standard Salesforce capabilities here, including digital experience site Self Registration?

Comment: Have you looked at [External Identity](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_identity_login_discovery.htm&type=5&release=216&language=en_US).  Note you would need to buy [add-on SMS Messaging licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_identity_sms_license.htm&type=5&release=216) for this.

Comment: @PhilW, yes, I mean don't send a welcome email.

Comment: You can easily turn that off in the digital experience site's admin workspace settings.